# add node to binary search tree recursively with errors

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have created a method that adds a new item to my binary search tree, I have no idea what I have wrong, but it does not add anything to my tree... I will annex my BTNode class and my add method. I would really appreciate some help/suggestions.

```
    public class BTNode
{
  public int item;
  public BTNode left;
  public BTNode right;

  public BTNode(int i, BTNode l, BTNode r)
  {
    item = i;
    left = l;
    right = r;
  }

  public String toString() 
  {
    return "[" + item + "]";
  }

}
```

//add Method

```
public BTNode add (BTNode node, int value)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new BTNode(value, null, null);
            return node;
        }
        else if (node.item > value)
            node.left = add(node.left, value);
        else if (node.item < value)
            node.right = add(node.right, value);

        return node;

    }
```

//tester

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

        BTNode root = new BTNode(70, null, null);
        BTNode n2   = new BTNode(20, null, null);
        BTNode n3   = new BTNode(10, null, null);
        BTNode n4   = new BTNode(27, null, null);
        BTNode n5   = new BTNode(150, null, null);
        BTNode n6   = new BTNode(115, null, null);
        BTNode n7   = new BTNode(300, null, null);
        root.left  = n2;
        root.right = n5;
        n2.left    = n3;
        n2.right   = n4;
        n5.left    = n6;
        n5.right   = n7;


        tree.add(root,32);


    }
```

Comment: what's the `error` exactly?

Comment: When trying to use the method add it doesn't add anything to the tree I have already created...

Comment: How do you realize that it doesn't change the tree? There are no queries over the tree or output? Would help to include some code that show's the error.

Comment: @AlexDelgado Sorry for the delay. Just updated the `fix` and made some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in these lines:

```
    if (node == null)
    {
        node = new BTNode(value, null, null);
        return node;
    } else if (xxx)
```

You have to change it to:

```
    if (node == null)
    {
        node = new BTNode(value, null, null);
        if(this.item>value) {
            left = node;
        } else {
            right = node;
        }
        return node;
    } else if (xxx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `main`, I'm assuming the `add` method belongs to the `BinarySearchTree` class.

Your add method works fine, but you have to display the tree in order to see that it works.

For example, if you modify your `BTNode`'s `toString()` method to display all the nodes of the sub-tree of a given node:

```
public String toString() 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (left != null) {
        sb.append (left.toString ());
    }
    sb.append ("[" + item + "]");
    if (right != null) {
        sb.append (right.toString ());
    }
    return sb.toString ();
}
```

You'll see that printing the `root` node:

```
System.out.println (root);
```

results in all the nodes, including the one you added with `tree.add(root,32);`:

```
[10][20][27][32][70][115][150][300]
```

One small issue with your `add` method is that it will not add a new node if a node with the same value is already present in the tree. I don't know if that's the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd encapsulate the `add` into `add(int val)` in the `BinarySearchTree` and here is a demo for it:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    private BTNode root;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

        tree.add(70);
        tree.add(20);
        tree.add(10);
        tree.add(27);
        tree.add(150);
        tree.add(115);
        tree.add(300);
        System.out.println(tree.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return root.toString();
    }

    public void add(int value) {
        root = add(root, value);
    }

    private BTNode add(BTNode node, int value) {
        if (node == null) {
            return new BTNode(value, null, null);
        }
        if (node.item > value)
            node.left = add(node.left, value);
        else if (node.item < value)
            node.right = add(node.right, value);
        return node;
    }

    static class BTNode {
        int item;
        BTNode left;
        BTNode right;

        BTNode(int i, BTNode l, BTNode r) {
            item = i;
            left = l;
            right = r;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { // return the pre-order traversal;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (left != null) stringBuilder.append(left.toString());
            stringBuilder.append("[" + item + "]");
            if (right != null) stringBuilder.append(right.toString());
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }
}
```